# angularjs values are not bound properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

suppose I have a directive `dir1`

```
myApp.directive('dir1', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/Templates/TestTmpl.html',
        scope: {
            selectedName: '=?',
            getSelectedName : '&?'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.bindSelectedName = function (name) {
                $scope.selectedName = name;
                $scope.getSelectedName();
            }
        }
    }
})
```

and this is the the HTML template specified in the template URL

```
<div ng-init="names=[
{name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
{name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
{name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}]">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"
       ng-click="bindSelectedName(name)"
       ng-repeat="name in names">
        {{name.name}}
    </a>
</div>
```

I want to bind the selected name to a controller, this is how the controller looks like

```
myApp.controller('ctrl1', function ($scope) {

    $scope.getSelectedName = function (name) {
        console.log(name);
    }
})
```

this is the HTML I'm using

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <dir1 data-selected-name="name" data-get-selected-name=getSelectedName(name)></dir1>
</div>
```

the problem now is when I check the value of `console.log(name);` in the controller `ctrl1` , it's not the same as the value of `$scope.selectedName` in `dir1`.

my question is what is wrong with the code above ? and what should I do to solve this issue ?

Comment: Why can't you just do `ng-click="bindSelectedName(name)"` to `ng-click="getSelectedName({'name': name})"` ?

Comment: What are the differences? Why do you even need `getSelectedName()` when you already have `name` bound both ways? Does removing `#` from href change anything? If using default hash based routing having `#` in href is problematic

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks this works fine actually

Comment: @charlietfl `#` wasn't the problem at all, it seems I wasn't using binding the right way

Comment: @NaderHisham Just making sure - Did changing the bindings to `ng-click="getSelectedName({'name': name})"` solved the problem?

Comment: yeah, it did, post the solution in your comment, I'll accept it.

Comment: No, that's fine :) just wanted to be sure I helped you with this. Thanks